# Function returning undefined values in an object after looping

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on my first JS project, a BlackJack game. I've written a function to create a deck, deck is an array of objects containing card's Suit, Value and Weight. 
As for the Weight, after looping the function returns undefined, Suit and Value are returned fine. Here is my code:

```
// Creation of the deck
function deckCreate() {
  for (let i = 0; i < cardSuits.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cardValues.length; j++) {
      let cardWeight = parseInt(cardValues[j]);
      if (cardValues[j] === "J" || cardValues[j] === "Q" || cardValues[j] === "K") {
        cardWeight = 10;
      } if (cardValues[j] === "A") {
        cardWeight = 11;
      }
      let card = {
        Suit: cardSuits[i],
        Value: cardValues[j],
        Weight: cardWeight[j]
      }; deck.push(card);
    }
  } return deck;
}
```

Beforehand I have the following variables created:

```
const cardSuits = ["&clubs;", "&hearts;", "&diams;", "&spades;"];
const cardValues = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"];
let deck = [];
```

The objects that are returned are: 
e.g.

```
0: {Suit: "&spades;", Value: "2", Weight: undefined}
1: {Suit: "&hearts;", Value: "10", Weight: undefined}
2: {Suit: "&clubs;", Value: "5", Weight: undefined}
```

And I can't seem to understand why the Weight is undefined. 
Would appreciate any help
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide **all** the related code so that we can run your example and reproduce your issue.

Comment: cardWeight is an `int` not an array. change

Comment: You are defining `cardWeight` as an integer: `let cardWeight = parseInt(cardValues[j]);` and later trying to index into it: `Weight: cardWeight[j]`

Comment: @MarkMeyer have changed it to "Weight: cardWeight", works now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cardWeight` is a number and not an array, which you get from this line:

```
// You are pulling a single value from an array here:
let cardWeight = parseInt(cardValues[j]);
```

so when you try to pass an index to it, you get `undefined` returned. Just access `cardWeight` as a single value:

```js
// Creation of the deck
let cardSuits = ["&Clubs", "&Spades", "&Diamonds", "&Hearts"];
let cardValues = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"J","Q","K","A"];
let deck = [];

function deckCreate() {
  for (let i = 0; i < cardSuits.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cardValues.length; j++) {
      let cardWeight = parseInt(cardValues[j]);
      if (cardValues[j] === "J" || cardValues[j] === "Q" || cardValues[j] === "K") {
        cardWeight = 10;
      } if (cardValues[j] === "A") {
        cardWeight = 11;
      }
      let card = {
        Suit: cardSuits[i],
        Value: cardValues[j],
        Weight: cardWeight // <-- This is a single value, not an array
      }; deck.push(card);
    }
  } return deck;
}

console.log(deckCreate());
```

Answer (score 2):

Corrected, removing [j]

```js
// Creation of the deck
function deckCreate() {
  for (let i = 0; i < cardSuits.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cardValues.length; j++) {
      let cardWeight = parseInt(cardValues[j]);
      if (cardValues[j] === "J" || cardValues[j] === "Q" || cardValues[j] === "K") {
        cardWeight = 10;
      } if (cardValues[j] === "A") {
        cardWeight = 11;
      }
      let card = {
        Suit: cardSuits[i],
        Value: cardValues[j],
        Weight: cardWeight
      }; deck.push(card);
    }
  } return deck;
}

const cardSuits = ["&clubs;", "&hearts;", "&diams;", "&spades;"];
const cardValues = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"];
var deck = [];

console.log(deckCreate());
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `Weight: cardWeight[j]` to `Weight: cardWeight`